# Emberjs itemController / controller property binding

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I've made a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/diraqecupi/1/edit?html,css,js,output) to illustrate my issue.

the binding seems KO with lastname property defined inside the itemController and the fullname value is not updated in my items loop.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Sorry, i mean it doesn't work

Comment: Everything works. http://jsbin.com/dupurefaku/1/

Comment: @MateuszNowak No, it doesn't. Don't you see `fullname` in items list has always `bar` instead of `lastname` specified in input?

Comment: @Daniel http://jsbin.com/munetekobu/1/ Now?

Comment: @Jad I think you're facing here design problem. Why do you specify `lastname` in itemController? If you want to get default value when it's not specified in `Model` you could check if `lastname` is null and only then return `bar`, but since you specify it in Controller it's causes problems. @MateuszNowak It works, but for some reason @Jad wants this property specified in `Controller`.

Comment: @Daniel I made this example to illustrate my issue, the property that I am trying to bind doesn't persist so I don't want to put it in my model.

Comment: @Jad Do you use Ember Data?

Answer (score 0):

Controller for item in list is different than one you edit property `lastname` for, so it will never get updated. Propery `lastname` has to be specified as Model's property (if using Ember Data you simply don't use `DS.attr` for it and it won't be persisted). If you use custom library for data persistence you have to manually remove `lastname` property. You can use Ember Inspector extension to see that there are 5 controllers when you click on item. 4 for each item in list and one is being generated when you click. You edit property `lastname` for this fifth controller. To solve this you can use:
JavaScript:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
 this.resource('items', function() {
   this.resource('item', {path: '/:item_id'});
 });
});

App.Model = Ember.Object.extend({
   firstname: 'foo',
   lastname: 'bar',
   fullname: function() {
     return this.get('firstname') + ' ' + this.get('lastname');
   }.property('firstname', 'lastname')
});

App.ItemsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return [App.Model.create({id: 1}), App.Model.create({id: 2}), App.Model.create({id: 3}), App.Model.create({id: 4})];
  }
});

App.ItemRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.modelFor('items').findBy('id', +params.item_id);
  }
});
```

Templates:

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h2>Welcome to Ember.js</h2>
    {{link-to "items" "items"}}
    {{outlet}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="items">
    <ul>
    {{#each item in model}}
      <li>
        {{#link-to 'item' item.id}}
        {{item.fullname}} {{item.id}}
        {{/link-to}}
      </li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>

    {{outlet}}
  </script>

   <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="item">
     {{input value=model.firstname}}
      {{input value=model.lastname}}
      {{model.fullname}}
  </script>
```

Please keep in mind that `ArrayController` and `ObjectController` aren't recommended to use, because they will be deprecated in future. [Demo.](http://jsbin.com/heqacoqoku)